# Facebook API v2.0: can you use ruby to change the app_scoped_id into username?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

WHen you make calls to the new facebook API v2.0 you can no longer get the username, but you can get the app_scoped_id   http://facebook.com/app_scoped_id/XXXXXXXXXXXXX. When pasted into a browser this turns into http://facebook.com/username, is there a way with ruby to turn id into a username?

Comment: If there is no way to do that using the API, I suppose you can just issue a `GET` or `HEAD` request to the app_scoped URL and look at the `Location` header of the response; it should contain the username URL (I assume they use a regular HTTP 30x redirect response).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am not familiar with FQL, could you help with an answer that provides a code snippet of an FQL query that would accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by FQL. What I meant was do a HEAD request to your `app_scoped_id/x``` url and look at the 'location' key which should contain the `facebook.com/username` url if it is a standard redirect. Try this with your `xxx` filled in, what does it print?: `require 'net/http';Net::HTTP.start('facebook.com'){|http| p http.head('/app_scoped_id/xxx')['location']}`